# Merge and sum certain item property in array of objects

Tags: php

I have an array of objects that needs to have distinct item.
Basically, certain similar property values should be added together.

For instance, what I want is an item that has repeated user_id to be merged and have its point summed together:

```
$data = [
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "point": 2
  },
  {
    "user_id": 16,
    "point": 3
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "point": 10
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "point": 10
  }
]
```

This is the desired result I'm expecting:

```
$data = [
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "point": 22
  },
  {
    "user_id": 16,
    "point": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where does the JSON come from?

Comment: Something like https://3v4l.org/YHCVJ could be used.. seeing what you've tried might help us see what issues you've run into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First turn your JSON format data into array using `json_decode` function.

```php
$users = json_decode($data, true);
```

- Group your data by `user_id`.

```php
$groupedById = array_reduce($users, function ($accumulator,$user) {
  $accumulator[$user['user_id']][] = $user;
  return $accumulator;
}, []);
```

- Calculate the sum of points by accumulate the `point` of each users grouped by `user_id`.

```php
foreach ($groupedById as $users) {
    $sumPoints = array_sum(array_column($users, 'point'));
    $result[] = ['user_id'=>$users[0]['user_id'], 'point'=>$sumPoints];
}
```

- Print Result.

```php
echo json_encode($result);
```

```json
[{"user_id":2,"point":22},
{"user_id":16,"point":3}]
```